# Binding a combobox selectedvalue to a data class

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I have a page with a number of fields on it that I'm using to create a new class record called Account. One of the fields is a currency code that is set via a combobox. The combobox is bound to a datatable with an id and a description. I'm trying to use binding so that the selectedvalue of the combobox automatically updates the currency id of the Account class. So far no joy...

Class definition:

```
class Account : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int CurrencyID { get; set; }
    public int BankID { get; set; }
    public String AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal OpeningBalance { get; set; }

 ... other definitions for validation handling ...

}
```

Combobox definition:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboCurrency" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
     SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Account.CurrencyID, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=true}"
     ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=cboCurrency, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
```

Page constructor:

```
public AccountAdd()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    base.DataContext = new Account();

    // Load the Currency combo with the list of currencies
    //
    cboCurrency.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
    cboCurrency.SelectedValuePath = "_id";
    cboCurrency.ItemsSource = _DBUtils.getCurrencyList().DefaultView;


}
```

Save Code:

```
private void btnAccountOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Account newAccountRec = (Account)base.DataContext;

    int newid = _DBUtils.AddAccount(newAccountRec);
}
```

Comment: your code should work when the columnname for the id column of your datatable is: "_id" and the type should be int. is that the case? and like clemens suggested your path should be just CurrencyID

Comment: yes, the id column does need to be "_id" in the db and it is of type int. I can always rename it in the query if needed, though I wouldn't think that would make much of a difference to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ComboBox's DataContext is set to an Account instance, its SelectedValue should bind to `CurrencyID`, not `Account.CurrencyID`:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrencyID, ...}" ... />
```

Also (if your datatable is a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9186hy08)) create a collection of objects with appropriate properties from each table row for the ComboBox's items, as suggested by blindmeis:

```
cboCurrency.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";  
cboCurrency.SelectedValuePath = "Id";  
cboCurrency.ItemsSource =
    _DBUtils.getCurrencyList().Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(
        row => new { Name = row["Name"], Id = row["_id"] });
```

Comment: When I do that I get a validation error: value '4' could not be converted. Where '4' is the currency id. both the id in the combo and in the account are integers, so I don't get where the conversion is needed.

Comment: Is `_id` a public property of the currency class? It has to be that. See [SelectedValuePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath).

Comment: _id is the id column of the datatable returned by the getCurrencyList query method. Its not a part of the Account class. I'm trying to map it to the CurrencyID field in the Account class.

Comment: That's what i meant, it has to be converted into a public property to be useful for `SelectedValuePath`. See edited answer.

Comment: I tried setting the xaml & code behind as you suggested in your edited example, but I'm still getting the value could not be converted error.

Comment: The datatable row entry for `_id` is perhaps returned as a string. Is that possible?

Comment: Paranoia made me check - its an integer. Its a SQLite db, but I don't think that should make any difference, as retrieved integers work fine in other parts of the code.

Comment: Sorted it - I put a convert around the id:             cboCurrency.ItemsSource = _DBUtils.getCurrencyList().Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => new { Name = row["Name"], Id = Convert.ToInt32(row["_id"]) });

Comment: Great. Have you found out what the actual type is? Maybe `short` or `long`.

Comment: its a long in the db - that maps to int32 in c#. I think long would work too

Answer (score 0):

you could use anonym types for easier binding (drawback you have to set the itemssource everytime getcurrecylist changed)

code is not tested:

```
//i assume that your columns names are "Name" and "_id"
cboCurrency.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
cboCurrency.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
cboCurrency.ItemsSource = _DBUtils.getCurrencyList().AsEnumerable().Select(x => new {Name = x["Name"], Id = x["_id"]}).ToList;

//lostfocus makes no sense or?
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrencyID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=true}"
```

Comment: getCurrencyList returns a datatable and doesn't support AsEnumerable. I tried removing that and just using the Select, but then I get the error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"